# Pandas - retrieve original dataframe from transformed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I builded a dataframe to save the stocks consituent of a stock index over time with the following steps:

1)First, I download the raw data through a data provider and store in a dict

2)Transform into a dataframe to obtain:

```
constituent_pd = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(constituent, orient='index')

index  col1     col2    col3  etc...
1/1/92 stockA  stockB  NA     etc...
2/1/92 stockB  stockC  stockD etc...
```

3)Tranform into a boolean dataframe with:

```
constituent_bol = pd.get_dummies(constituent_pd.stack()).max(level=0).astype(bool)

index  stockA  stockB  stockC etc...
1/1/92 True    True    False  etc...
2/1/92 False   True    True   etc...
```

From there, I'have been trying to find a way to quickly update my table.
To do so, I'd need to reconvert back constituent_bin to its original dictionary form, merge it with a new dictionart (for more recent dates) and restart the entire process.

```
step1 = constituent_bol.astype('int32')
step2 = step1[step1 ==1].stack().reset_index().drop(0,1).set_index('level_0')

1/1/92 stockA
1/1/92 stockB
etc...
```

and I don't know how to reshape this long dataframe like constituent_pd to obtain a dic later.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What is your input dictionary?

Comment: date1: stockA, stockB,...
date2: stockB, stockC, stockD,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in function `max(level=0)` lost original columns names, because it aggregate by first level.

So close what you need is possible use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter for new columns names:

```
print (constituent_pd)
          col1    col2    col3
index                         
1/1/92  stockA  stockB     NaN
2/1/92  stockB  stockC  stockD
```

---

```
print (pd.get_dummies(constituent_pd.stack()))
             stockA  stockB  stockC  stockD
index                                      
1/1/92 col1       1       0       0       0
       col2       0       1       0       0
2/1/92 col1       0       1       0       0
       col2       0       0       1       0
       col3       0       0       0       1

print (pd.get_dummies(constituent_pd.stack()).max(level=0))
        stockA  stockB  stockC  stockD
index                                 
1/1/92       1       1       0       0
2/1/92       0       1       1       1
```

---

```
constituent_bol = pd.get_dummies(constituent_pd.stack()).max(level=0).astype(bool)
print (constituent_bol)
        stockA  stockB  stockC  stockD
index                                 
1/1/92    True    True   False   False
2/1/92   False    True    True    True
```

---

```
step1 = constituent_bol.astype('int32')
step2 = step1[step1 == 1].stack().reset_index().drop(0,1)
step2 = step2.set_index(['index', step2.groupby('index').cumcount()])['level_1'].unstack()
print (step2)
             0       1       2
index                         
1/1/92  stockA  stockB     NaN
2/1/92  stockB  stockC  stockD
```